# How to tunnel using OpenVPN on Windows

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, ssh-tunnel

I successfully establish a SSH connection on Windows using the OpenVPN GUI. To reach ABC servers, I need to use a tunnel. How can I manage to set up a HTTP tunneling according to this manual:

> The ABC servers are not directly routed through the VPN.
>   However, once a VPN connection to F-City has been established via
>   OpenVPN, **there are two ways** to access J and the W. The
>   examples below use ServerP (x.x.x.x) as SSH hop, which can
>   access the target servers.

*1. way*

> SSH Tunnel
>
> The SSH connection from OpenVPN Client to ServerP
>   with HTTP tunneling:
>
> `ssh -L 8000:y.y.y.y:80 ServerP`

**Where do I have to set this `ssh` command in OpenVPN to use HTTP tunneling?**

*2. way*

> SOCKS Proxy
>
> SSH connection from OpenVPN Client to ServerP with
>   activation of a SOCKS proxy:
>
> `ssh -D 8000 ServerP`

**Where do I have to set this `ssh` command in OpenVPN to use a SOCKS Proxy?**

Answer (score 2):

You don't 'normally' set the command for openvpn to use ssh; the SSH tunnel is actually something that makes use of the OpenVPN connection.

So, install putty, and in the settings you can configure the tunnel. From here the rest of your instructions should start to make more sense to you! - [Putty tunneling tutorial](http://blog.ashurex.com/2012/03/15/creating-ssh-proxy-tunnel-putty/)

Comment: Yes I have tried using putty, setting the host of ServerP and under SSH->Tunnels, I set the Source port and Dest, but it does not work. What could be the problem?

Comment: I have followed the tutorial exactly as described. My connection in putty is established, but the website does not load, how can I test the connection in the putty terminal?